# Why is string localization/internationalization not working in SwiftUI?

Tags: string, localization, internationalization, swiftui

I've got text in my app that's supposed to be localized, like

```
  Text(self.model.stringValue)
```

where `.stringValue = "dist"`, and I've created Localized.strings and added the reference

```
  "dist" = "the distance";
```

The documentation says that Text views automatically interpret strings as localization keys and look them up for you:

```
 Text("pencil") // Searches the default table in the main bundle.
```

I've clicked "Localize" on the strings file and added languages to the project file and answers like this say it's supposed to just work: [How to implement localization in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578341/how-to-implement-localization-in-swift-ui)

But instead it's just displaying "dist" instead of the proper localized string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the string in Text("pencil") is only interpreted as a localization key if you pass it as a **literal**. If you pass a variable of type String, this doesn't happen. The answer is instead to declare the variable of type LocalizedStringKey.

```
  Text("dist") //-> implicitly treats string literal as a key; looks up and displays "the distance"
  let cap1:String = "dist"
  Text(cap1)   //-> no lookup for explicit String variable; just displays "dist"
  let cap2:LocalizedStringKey = "dist"
  Text(cap2)   //-> looks up explicit LocalizedStringKey value; displays "the distance"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make it localized inline, as

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(self.model.stringValue))
```