# SwiftUI Localization

Tags: swiftui

I am facing localisation issue in SwiftUI. Issue is happening when translation has placeholder. I am getting error **"Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'LocalizedStringKey' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'"**

### Code

```
struct Translation {
    struct school{
        static var location: LocalizedStringKey {
            return "schoolLocation %@"
        }
     }
}
```

### Translation file

"schoolLocation %@" = "My school location is  %@";

### SwiftUI view

```
var location = "Some Name"
.navigationBarTitle("\(Translation.school.location) \(location)")
```

Please help me if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement localization in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578341/how-to-implement-localization-in-swift-ui)

Comment: No, I have placeholder for dynamic value and for key i am  maintaining in structure of LocalizedStringKey.  My code is working perfectly for static localization values. but i am getting compilation error for dynamic value.

Comment: @Rocker have you tried removing `%@` from the key as it's not necessary? 
you can have "schoolLocation" = "My school location is %@"; in your translation file.

Comment: Still have getting compilation error "Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'LocalizedStringKey' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'" on line .navigationBarTitle("\(Translation.school.location) \(location)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is you are giving back an already interpolated string with `%@` to an interpolated string. So the string that you are generating looks like this: `"schoolLocation %@ Some Name"`. You can do it this way:

```
struct Translation {
    struct school{
        static func location(name: String): LocalizedStringKey {
            return "schoolLocation \(name)"
        }
     }
}
```

And then you can use your translation like this:

```
var location = "Some Name"
.navigationBarTitle(Translation.school.location(name: location))
```

Comment: Is there way we can assign localized value to String? There i am getting error